# How to properly contrl radio and select values using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set values of radio and select elements on the load of the page, if the current URL contains `type` and `annee` params, then I set those params as values of the radio and the select else if this does not, I set them to 1 and 2014 respectively.

I'm using this code to deal with this:

html

```
<span class="form-group" ng-controller="FiltreFicheController as ffCtl">
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="1" style="margin-left:10px;" ng-change="ffCtl.checkRadio(1)" ng-checked="ffCtl.isChecked(1)"> Tout
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="4" ng-change="ffCtl.checkRadio(4)" ng-checked="ffCtl.isChecked(4)"> 4 mois
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="6" ng-change="ffCtl.checkRadio(6)" ng-checked="ffCtl.isChecked(6)"> 6 mois
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="8" ng-change="ffCtl.checkRadio(8)" ng-checked="ffCtl.isChecked(8)"> 8 mois
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="12" ng-change="ffCtl.checkRadio(12)" ng-checked="ffCtl.isChecked(12)"> 12 mois
    <select name="annee" ng-model="annee">
        <option value="2014" ng-selected="ffCtrl.isSelected(2014)">2014</option>
        <option value="2000" ng-selected="ffCtrl.isSelected(2000)">2000</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

js

```
app.controller('FiltreFicheController', function($scope, $location){
        var link = document.URL;
        var type_param = (!location.search.indexOf('?', link)?location.search.split('type=')[1].split('&')[0]:'undefined');
        var annee_param = (!location.search.indexOf('?', link)?location.search.split('annee=')[1]:'undefined');
        this.type = (type_param!=='undefined'?type_param:1);
        this.annee = (annee_param!=='undefined'?annee_param:2014);

        this.isChecked = function(numRadio){
            return this.type === numRadio;
        }

        this.isSelected = function(annee){
            alert(link);
            return this.select === annee;
        }

        this.checkRadio = function(numRadio){
            this.type = numRadio;
            window.location.href = link.substring(link.indexOf('/'),link.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/fiche?type=' + numRadio + '&annee=' + this.annee;
        }
    });
```

But this wouldn't work. It works only when there are no params set into the URL and only sets the `type` radio to 1.

How do I fix this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you use ng-model with checkbox and radio?

Comment: @maurycy, I did, please look at the html posted code.

Comment: Sorry, i missed it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `type_param` and thus `this.type` are of type string, but your numRadio argument is of type int. so it checks f.e. 2 === "2" which is false.

So you can do `this.type = (type_param!=='undefined'?parseInt(type_param):1);`

Answer (score 0):

check my plunker with working code and a bit different approach, i've removed all the ng-change to make it cleaner

http://plnkr.co/edit/w61cKtp1eNnL31EL5GPR?p=preview

```
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="1" style="margin-left:10px;" > Tout
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="4" > 4 mois
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="6" > 6 mois
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="8" > 8 mois
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="type" value="12" > 12 mois
```